# How to accept a user input from the console but not use gets.chomp

Tags: ruby, string, user-input, gets

As I understand it, the way to accept user input is

```
puts "Can you guess what number the computer is thinking of?"
userguess = gets.chomp
```

`gets.chomp` is a string method and so if the user enters the number `5`, `userguess` stores the value `"5"` as string. I would then have to do `userguess.to_i!` to convert this to an int. However, I would not like to do this. I want to accept the user input either as a string or an int and then have the program do something like:

```
if @guess.is_a?(Integer) == true
  puts "I got your number. Let me get back to you."
  # do something
elsif @guess.is_a?(Integer) == false
  puts "That's not a number. You MUST enter a number! Try again"
  # Ask the user to guess again.
else
  #something else
end
```

I don't want to accept the user input explicitly as a string because I want to check if it is a string or an int later on in the program. How would I do this?

Comment: Anything input will be read as a string. You must handle type coercion yourself

Comment: Thanks, @Brennan. Then how would I distinguish between whether user input was a string or a number?

Comment: Your understanding that the way to accept an input is `gets.chomp` is wrong in the first place. The way to accept is `gets`. And there is no such thing as `to_i!`. Changing the receiver's class while retaining its id is impossible.

Comment: You could use a regex: `s = gets.chomp; if s[/^-?\d+$/] ....` –  Cary Swoveland 7 mins ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

But you can define a little function to check whether that string can be an integer or not:

```
def is_i?(s)
  s.to_i.to_s == s
end
```

Be aware that string with spaces will not be an integer in this case:

```
is_i? '123'    # true
is_i? '123 '   # false
is_i? ' 123'   # false
is_i? '12 123' # false
```

To handle second and third example you can strip your user input.

Your code will look like:

```
guess = gets.chomp.strip

if is_i? guess
  puts 'is integer' 
else
  puts 'is not an integer'
end
```

Comment: You might want to rename it `is_integer?`,  as `is_number?(2.4) => false`.

Comment: You might want to rename it `is_integer?`, as `is_i?('i') => false`. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I will rename it when `to_s` will always return `'s'` :)

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. All user input from the terminal are a string. If it were possible, how would you think a user can input a number `5` as opposed to a string `"5"`?

Comment: Looks too small to be an answer, no? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Besides giving an answer like this, the only other way I can think of is to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string contains valid integer (or float, etc.) you could use this approach:

```
def coerce(string)
  Integer(string) rescue Float(string) rescue string
end 

coerce('115').class      # Fixnum
coerce('115.12').class   # Float
coerce('115.aa').class   # String
```

Also check out [highline gem](https://github.com/JEG2/highline), it provides lots of helpful functionality when it comes to cli.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how a keyboard device and the console input work.

*ALL* input typed on the keyboard and read via `gets` or anything else, is *always* a String. You can not get anything else.

We use `gets.chomp` to remove the trailing newline that is entered when the user presses <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For instance, a bare `gets` will return a line-end if I enter nothing else:

```
gets #=> "\n"
```

Adding additional characters results in those characters, plus the terminating line-end:

```
gets #=> "foo\n"
```

We use `chomp` to remove that trailing line-end. Repeating the same inputs and using `chomp`:

```
gets.chomp #=> ""
gets.chomp #=> "foo"
```

Ruby makes it easy to tell if what was input can be cleanly converted to an integer. Simply use `Integer()`. Here is some output from an IRB session:

```
>> Integer('1') #=> 1
>> Integer('123') #=> 123
>> Integer('foo')
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "foo"
    from (irb):14:in `Integer'
    from (irb):14
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> Integer('1a')
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1a"
    from (irb):15:in `Integer'
    from (irb):15
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Using a `rescue` makes it easy to handle the exception:

```
begin
  Integer('1')
rescue ArgumentError
  puts 'not a number'
end #=> 1
```

Or:

```
begin
  Integer('a')
rescue ArgumentError
  'not a number'
end #=> "not a number"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Appreciate your help